# In "Han i glei net allweil bei dir sein", what is the word "han"?

Tags: meaning, german-to-english, lyrics, swabian

In the song 'Muss i denn, muss i denn zum Städtele hinaus',  there is a statement

> Han i glei net allweil bei dir sein

What's the original word `han` here? Can't guess what it is in the dictionary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The citing of the verse is inaccurate. Actually it reads:

> **Kann** ('can') i glei net allweil bei dir sein

---

There is, however, the word *han* in the **next verse**:

> **Han** ('have') i doch mei Freud’ an dir!

*Han i* is Swabian dialect and means *habe ich* ('have I') in Standard German. Thus its dictionary form is *haben*.

Comment: I thank you so much!